# Extract Multiple Values from Single String With Same Pattern in Mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

I have a block of delimited text in a single string in Mysql that I need to Parse. The block looks as follows

```
BGN|1
TST|12345|5
END|1
BGN|2
TST|22345|6
END|2
BGN|3
TST|67554|7
END|3
```

I would like to extract the value immediately after TST, `12345`, `22345`,`67554` into separate records (not concatenated), so the results would look like

```
12345
22345
64554
```

I am able to parse strings using the Locate value but I am unsure of how to get multiple values out of the data with the single locate command. In SQL Server this is no problem for me.

Edit: I realize I can probably use substring_index in a loop but I'd prefer to not run loops through the string.

Comment: You do not really have much choice in this regard: substring_index or use an external programming language

Comment: Or even better, store the data in individual rows and columns if you need to access individual sub-elements of the data.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c, '|', 2), SUBSTRING_INDEX(c, '|', 1), ''), 2) AS 'TST'
FROM
    test_data
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(c, '|', 1) = 'TST';
```

***Output***:

```
+-------+
| TST   |
+-------+
| 12345 |
| 22345 |
| 67554 |
+-------+
```

Using `mysql's SUBSTRING_INDEX` function you can extract substring from string before count occurrences of the delimiter (`|`) and combining with `REPLACE` and `SUBSTRING` you can extract the desired values.

Or if your second field has a fixed length then:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(c, 5, 5) AS 'TST'
FROM
    test_data
WHERE SUBSTRING(c, 1, 3) = 'TST';
```

See a [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df548/5).

Where `test_data` table looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (c TEXT);

INSERT INTO test_data(c) VALUES
('BGN|1'),
('TST|12345|5'),
('END|1'),
('BGN|2'),
('TST|22345|6'),
('END|2'),
('BGN|3'),
('TST|67554|7'),
('END|3');
```